# How to add or delete custom option in many products in magento 1.9.3.6?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, ce-1.9.1.0, magento1.9.3

is there any feature available in magento to add or remove custom option in many products?

I want to give some free service with product to customer. Customer can select or unselect checkbox whether he wants to get free service with products or not. it's customer choice that's why I want to use custom option. I have added free service in custom option. I want to apply this custom option in many products. How can i do this?

If adding or deleting custom option is not available in magento. is there any other alternative way to achieve this feature?

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 1.9.x you can add/remove options only one-by-one. Alternative way will be to use extension. For one-off occasion you can use free version of tool introduced in this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=162&v=FNU4v4aATaU) that possess necessary functionality.